# Unable to Hibernate: Swap header not found

Tags: 18.04, swap, hibernate

I hadn't allocated any swap partition while installing ubuntu before so I couldn't hibernate my laptop which gave error: couldn't find swap device,try swapon. I then created a swap partition using GParted of size about 10Gb and checked on swapon.

[image: Gparted]

I then checked the size of swap in terminal, 
[image: terminal]

[image: fstab]

I don't understand what this means and I am not sure what should I do after this. Still, I am unable to hibernate and now it says Swap header not found. What should I do to solve this problem?

Comment: It means you have both a swapfile and a swap partition. Are they both defined in your `/etc/fstab`?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1UaDUnzUISFUUurOLOLyqjx8_EU7WEVbP
Does this mean that my swap partition is not defined?

Comment: [Please don't post images of text](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/8713/85695). Instead, paste the text directly into your question and use the [formatting tools](https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting).

Comment: @rima hi I’m having the same error msg. How did you solve the problem?

Comment: @athos I am unable to hibernate so I suspend it instead.